# how can i get the content in my footer to have linebreaks between each link

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my web app adaptive and cannot get the resize of the page to affect the display of the `<br>` tags.

```css
.newline-resize {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .newline-resize {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<a href="{% url 'IOTD:logout' %}"> Log Out</a>
<br class="newline-resize">
<a href="{% url 'IOTD:myAccount' %}"> My Image</a>
<br class="newline-resize">
<a href="{% url 'IOTD:voteImage' %}"> Vote For An Image</a>
<br class="newline-resize">
<a href="{% url 'IOTD:upload' %}"> Upload An Image</a>
<br class="newline-resize">
```

Comment: is there a specific reason to use `<br>` in the first place? You could also use media queires to change the anchor in a block level element `footer a { display: block; }` to make them display below each other without using linebreaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a more simple and clean solution for what you trying to do:

anchors are by default `inline elements`. You can use `media queries` simply to target all the anchors within your footer and change them to block level elements. As block level elements they will be displayed below each other even without linebreaks:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  footer a {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a href="{% url 'IOTD:logout' %}"> Log Out</a>
  <a href="{% url 'IOTD:myAccount' %}"> My Image</a>
  <a href="{% url 'IOTD:voteImage' %}"> Vote For An Image</a>
  <a href="{% url 'IOTD:upload' %}"> Upload An Image</a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working

```css
.newline-resize {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .newline-resize {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<a href="{% url 'IOTD:logout' %}"> Log Out</a>
<br class="newline-resize">
<a href="{% url 'IOTD:myAccount' %}"> My Image</a>
<br class="newline-resize">
<a href="{% url 'IOTD:voteImage' %}"> Vote For An Image</a>
<br class="newline-resize">
<a href="{% url 'IOTD:upload' %}"> Upload An Image</a>
<br class="newline-resize">
```

Comment: thats really weird could there be any reason this isnt working on my end even though the code is correct

Answer (score 1):

Add the `newline-resize` class to your `a` tag - not the `<br>`.

[MDN break reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

What you'll need to do is modify the `a` tag - probably by adding a margin to the bottom - when your breakpoint is hit. Something like the following should work.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.newline-resize {
    margin-bottom: 1rem; // or whatever you want
}
```